# Why does it not like my arrays of TextFields, hBoxes, and Labels?

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, textfield, hbox

I am using JavaFX and this is my code. I am trying to make a column of five labels, textfields and hBoxes.

```
    Label[] lblTask = new Label[5];
    TextField[] taskTF = new TextField[5];
    HBox[] hb = new HBox[5];

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        hb[i].getChildren().addAll(lblTask[i],taskTF[i]);
        hb[i].setSpacing(10);
        hb[i].setLayoutX(30);
        hb[i].setLayoutY(120+(60*i));
        root.getChildren().add(hb[i]);
    }
```

It is giving me a java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException, and java.lang.RuntimeException and a java.lang.NullPointerException on the line that I set the spacing!

Comment: Your arrays are empty, you need to create each element of the array explicitly.

Comment: On the first iteration of the loop, what do you think the value of (for example) `hb[0]` is?